# How do I call a base class implementation of an explicitly impemented interface method?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call an explicitly implemented interface method implemented on the base class but just can't seem to get it to work. I agree the idea is ugly as hell, but I've tried every combination I can think of, to no avail. In this case, I can change the base class, but thought I'd ask the question to satisfy my general curiosity.

Any ideas?

```
// example interface
interface MyInterface
{
    bool DoSomething();
}

// BaseClass explicitly implements the interface
public class BaseClass : MyInterface
{
    bool MyInterface.DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

// Derived class 
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Also explicitly implements interface
    bool MyInterface.DoSomething()
    {
        // I wish to call the base class' implementation
        // of DoSomething here
        ((MyInterface)(base as BaseClass)).DoSomething(); // does not work - "base not valid in context"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot (it is not part of the interface available to subclasses). In that scenario, use something like:

```
// base class
bool MyInterface.DoSomething()
{
    return DoSomething();
}
protected bool DoSomething() {...}
```

Then any subclass can call the protected `DoSomething()`, or (better):

```
protected virtual bool DoSomething() {...}
```

Now it can just override rather than re-implement the interface:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override bool DoSomething()
    {
        // changed version, perhaps calling base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: @cristobalito as an aside... you *can* do that more directly in VB.NET; that, however, is not reason enough to switch language ;p

Comment: No chance of that happening Marc!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why C# can't support `((IInterface)base)` if VB.NET can?
It would be helpful when you are adding functionality to a library whose code you do not own. The only other options are reflection and wrapping a second base class instance. It can be a nightmare to keep the two instances in sync.