# How to use the base implementation of an overridden abstract member?

Tags: f#, abstract, member, overriding

There are an interface (say IA), an implementation (say Base) of the interface IA, and a derived class of Base (say Derived) which overrides an abstract member of IA. Now, in the implementation of the overridden member, I want to use the implementation of the member of Base. However, I don't know how to write to do so.

This code illustrates my question:

```
type Flag =
  | F1 = 1
  | F2 = 2

type IA =
  abstract member A: Flag

type Base() =
  interface IA with
    member this.A = F1

type Derived() =
  inherit Base()

  interface IA with
    override this.A = (* ? *)
      // base.A ||| F2             // NG (Compile error that `A` isn't a member of `base`)
      // (base :> IA).A ||| F2     // NG (Syntax error)
      // (this :> IA).A ||| F2     // NG (Infinite recursion)
```

Comment: Not sure about this one - I thought `((this :> Base) :> IA).A` might have worked - but still stackoverflows

Comment: The base method is not public, do you can't call it from outside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually think there is no way to do this. F# interface implementations are similar to *explicit interface implementations* in C# and [you cannot call base implementation of an explicitly implemented interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582085/how-do-i-call-a-base-class-implementation-of-an-explicitly-impemented-interface).

The workaround is to modify the base class so that it is more like C# implicit interface implementation (which is sadly a bit cumbersome):

```
type Base() =
  // Define virtual property in class Base
  abstract A : Flag
  default this.A = Flag.F1
  // Implement IA via the virtual property
  interface IA with
    member this.A = this.A

type Derived() =
  inherit Base() 
  // Override the virtual property
  override this.A = base.A ||| Flag.F2
```

The following now returns 3 as expected:

```
(Derived() :> IA).A
```